# How can I fetch all rows in nodejs using promise and function?

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I created a promise with GetProducts. I'm calling my table named Products from mssql. But "resolve" only returns the first line. How can I return all rows?

Only when I run the stream all my rows come.
Best Regards.

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sql.connect(config, err => {
            const request = new sql.Request()
            request.stream = true
            request.query('select * from Products')
            request.on('row', row => {
                const products = [{ id: row.ProductID, name: row.ProductName}]
                resolve(products)
            })
        })
        sql.on('error', err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    })
}
```

Callback;

```
GetProducts()
    .then((products) => {
        console.log(products)
    });
```

Return;

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'Chai' } ]
```

Comment: It's coming back with one row because you're resolving the promise _the first time you get data from the stream_ instead of waiting for the whole stream to come back.  `request.on()` fires when data returns in the stream, but that data is not guaranteed to be the complete set of data from your query so you have to keep reading the stream and not resolve the promise until you know your data is complete. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45076533/75852

Comment: If you're not returning a large dataset, you'd be better off using `request.query(...).then(data => resolve(data))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows. First I returned my mssql query using Promise. Then I returned a while loop inside by calling this query. I don't know how correct my action is. But it works!

*Extract values from recordset of database using Node.js*

I'm sorry for my bad english.

```
const GetProductAll = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
        const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbconfig)
        let req = new sql.Request(pool)
        pool.connect((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err)
                return
            }
                req.query(`SELECT ProductID,ProductName FROM Products Order By ProductID asc`, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err)
                        return
                    } else {
                        const AllProducts = data
                        resolve(AllProducts)
                    }
                    pool.close()
                })
        })
        })
    }, 500);
}
```

Callback;

```
GetProductAll()
    .then((dataSQL) => {
        let i = 0;
        while (i < dataSQL.rowsAffected) {
            const quert = (dataSQL.recordset[i].ProductID + ' ' + dataSQL.recordset[i].ProductName);
            i++;
            console.log(quert)
        }
    })
```

Result;

```
1 Chai
2 Chang
3 Aniseed Syrup
4 Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning
5 Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix
6 Grandma's Boysenberry Spread
7 Uncle Bob's Organic Dried Pears
8 Northwoods Cranberry Sauce
9 Mishi Kobe Niku
10 Ikura
11 Queso Cabrales
12 Queso Manchego La Pastora
13 Konbu
14 Tofu
15 Genen Shouyu
16 Pavlova
17 Alice Mutton
18 Carnarvon Tigers
19 Teatime Chocolate Biscuits
20 Sir Rodney's Marmalade
21 Sir Rodney's Scones
22 Gustaf's Knäckebröd
23 Tunnbröd
24 Guaraná Fantástica
25 NuNuCa Nuß-Nougat-Creme
26 Gumbär Gummibärchen
27 Schoggi Schokolade
28 Rössle Sauerkraut
29 Thüringer Rostbratwurst
30 Nord-Ost Matjeshering
31 Gorgonzola Telino
32 Mascarpone Fabioli
33 Geitost
34 Sasquatch Ale
35 Steeleye Stout
36 Inlagd Sill
37 Gravad lax
38 Côte de Blaye
39 Chartreuse verte
40 Boston Crab Meat
41 Jack's New England Clam Chowder
42 Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee
43 Ipoh Coffee
44 Gula Malacca
45 Rogede sild
46 Spegesild
47 Zaanse koeken
48 Chocolade
49 Maxilaku
50 Valkoinen suklaa
51 Manjimup Dried Apples
52 Filo Mix
53 Perth Pasties
54 Tourtière
55 Pâté chinois
56 Gnocchi di nonna Alice
57 Ravioli Angelo
58 Escargots de Bourgogne
59 Raclette Courdavault
60 Camembert Pierrot
61 Sirop d'érable
62 Tarte au sucre
63 Vegie-spread
64 Wimmers gute Semmelknödel
65 Louisiana Fiery Hot Pepper Sauce
66 Louisiana Hot Spiced Okra
67 Laughing Lumberjack Lager
68 Scottish Longbreads
69 Gudbrandsdalsost
70 Outback Lager
71 Flotemysost
72 Mozzarella di Giovanni
73 Röd Kaviar
74 Longlife Tofu
75 Rhönbräu Klosterbier
76 Lakkalikööri
77 Original Frankfurter grüne Soße
```